# How to get parameters from a link that callls a jQuery function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<p class="half_text">
    <?php echo $upvotes; ?>
    <strong><a class="vote_up" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="#">Vote Up</a></strong> |
    <?php echo $downvotes; ?>
    <strong><a class="vote_down" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="#">Vote Down</a></strong>
</p>
```

and I have the jQuery code that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.vote_up').click(function() 
    {        
            alert("up");

alert ( "test: " + $(this).attr("problem_id") );

//                $(this).attr("data-problemID").

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(json)
                {           
                    // ? :)



                }
            });


        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });

    $('.vote_down').click(function() 
    {
        alert("down");

        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });    
});
</script>
```

How can I get the parameter value which is problem_id ?  If I add a url in the href parameter, I think the browser will just go to the url, no?  Otherwise - how can I pack parameter values into the jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to figure out is how to embed the problem ID in the link from your PHP so that you can fetch it when the link it clicked on, then you can put it a couple different places.  You can put an href on the link and fetch the problem ID from the href.  If you just do a `return(false)` from your click handler, then the link will not be followed upon click.

You can also put it as a custom attribute on the link tag like this:

```
<a class="vote_up" data-problemID="12" style="color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold;" href="#">Vote Up</a>
```

And, then in your jQuery click handler, you can retrieve it with this:

```
$(this).attr("data-problemID").
```

Comment: thank you. That is what I was looking for.  is that data parameter supported by all browsers? Is this the primary way to do such a thing?  Thanks!

Comment: Btw, you can try to take a look at it here, its returning undefined :( http://www.problemio.com

Comment: I modified my answer to use `.attr()`.  As best I know this will work in all browsers.

Comment: I am trying it out like this: alert ( "test: " + $(this).attr("problem_id") ); and that alerts undefined.

Comment: @Genadinik - I modified my code to use .attr().  The jQuery doc implies that `.data()` should have worked, but it clearly doesn't.  `.attr()` seems to work fine.

Comment: @Genadinik - It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WM6Nu/.  If your code doesn't work, then give us more specific reference to your exact code (so we don't have to find it in your site).  Note, when using `attr()`, you have to include the "data-" part in the request.  So, in your case it would be `$(this).attr("data-problem_id")`

Comment: @Genadinik - You need `$(this).attr("data-problem_id")`.

Comment: That data- thing was the part that was missing! Thanks, now works!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Because your `$.ajax` is defined in the same scope of the variable, you can use `problem_id` to obtain the variable value.

An overview of your current code:

```
var problem_id = "something"; //Defining problem_id
...

$.ajax(
  ...
  success: function(){
    ...
     //problem_id can also be accessed from here, because it has previously been 
     // defined in the same scope
    ...
 }, ...)
 ....
```

Comment: how do I obtain the variable if I am not sure how to send the variable in my HTML?

Comment: You have already defined `problem_id` in your code. If your real code has the same structure as your provided code, my solution will be sufficient. Otherwise: Show your real **relevant** code, instead of pseudo-code, and clearly phrase your wishes, if you want a better answer.

Comment: You haven't defined any input element with ID `problem_id`.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean, getting variables from the php page posted?

or to post?

anyway here's a snippet to replace the $.ajax

```
$.post('/problems/vote.php', {problem_id: problem_id, action: 'up'}, function(data) {
// data here is json, from the php page try logging or..
// console.log(data);
// alert(data.title);
}, 'json');
```

{problem_id: problem_id, action: 'up'} are the variables posted... use $_POST['problem_id'] and $_POST['action'] to process..

---

use simple variables names with jQuery.data and make sure you have latest jQuery..
let me try to round it up..

```
<a href="#" data-problemid="11" data-action="up" class="votelink">up</a>
<a href="#" data-problemid="11" data-action="down" class="votelink">down</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.votelink').click(function() {
    $.post('/problems/vote.php', {problem_id: $(this).data('problemid'), action: $(this).data('action')}, function(data) {
      // data here is json, from the php page try logging or..
      // console.log(data);
      // alert(data.title);
    }, 'json');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I need to get the value of the problem_id parameter.  Also, in the html snippet, how/where do I specify the value of the problem_id in there since my href="#" does not have any values?

Comment: <a href="#" data-problemid="11"></a> -- to retrieve, use $(this).data('problemid')